# Specifying Dockefile Path in Azure Pipelines

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We are trying to use Azure Pipelines to build Docker image for a Dot Net Core App. When setting up the pipeline if I check "default build context" will it automatically pick the Dockerfile from my root directory?

Dockerfile is currently in the root directory but I want to move the Dockerfile inside the api project. How do I setup the pipeline so the docker build command is executed from root directory but refer to Dockerfile inside the project?

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I haven't tried this, but something like this should work:

```
- task: Docker@1
  inputs:
    containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
    dockerRegistryEndpoint: my_service_connection
    imageName: bla-bla-bla
    dockerFile: src/app/dockerfile
    buildContext: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#task-inputs

Version 2 of the task has support for setting build context:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how do I set the Build context without yml file? There is no option to set that. I have added a screenshot in the original post

Comment: which version of the task are you using? you should use version 2.

Comment: I am using Task Version 1 as in version 2 it doesn't allow me to choose "Container Registry type" as Container Registry

Comment: you dont need to, just pick the proper registry from the dropdown

Comment: just create a service connection for the docker registry?

Comment: well I want to push to ECR and use the AWS task to do that..it seems Container Registry is removed in Task Version 2?

Comment: no, it works fine for me. i can see the private registry connection in the drop down. you need to create it first, obviously

Comment: Thanks, without build context the build happens where the docker file reside

Comment: as it normally would